# Trouble in views on android with onclick at RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, onclick, android-relativelayout

i'm having the next problem.

I have two layouts, one behind the other. When I click on the first view the "click" pass trough the view and it arrives at the second one. How can i stop the onclick only for the first view and enable it when i want at the second view?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

A image with my problem

[image]

2EDIT

Why am i doing this? Because i put im my app a menu like facebook. So i have the menu in the red view and i animate the green to the right to see the complete menu. See http://venturebeat.com/2011/12/07/facebook-for-android-upgraded-with-better-navigation-faster-photo-views/. Seems that the solutions is with set the view clickable to false.

Comment: Can you little bit more clear? Also it will be helpful if you show us some piece of your code which has problem.

Comment: sorry for my words..i think now its more clear.

Comment: did you try green.setClickable(false)?

Comment: i want the opposite..so can i do red.setclickable(false)? and then enable it on some other part? i'm going to test it. thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the `onClick` code?

Comment: you can change layout in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what and how do you want to achieve, but it doesn't seem to be a good idea to have RelativeLayouts on top of each other. For this you could use a FrameLayout, or if your layout is a bit more complicated, you could play with setting the views unclickable.

If this doesn't help you, please post some code.

EDIT

It's still not too clear why do you want to achieve this, but you can set the second view unclickable, whenever you want.

Comment: All i want is that the click on the green view can't trough to the red, it's that possible?